# Oracle Triggers - before any UPDATE or DELETE or INSERT

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-sql-developer

I am trying to create a database trigger in Oracle SQL Developer that would fire before any `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` statement occurs on the *sessions* table.

My sessions table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
SessionNo NUMBER (2,0),
SessionTime VARCHAR2 (5),
SessionDay VARCHAR2 (20),
SessionDate DATE,
SpecID VARCHAR2 (2),
RoomNo CHAR (3),
BuildingNo CHAR (2),
FormID CHAR (4));
```

My example insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO sessions VALUES (1, '9', 'Monday', TO_DATE ('02/06/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),
                        12, 108, 'M', 0050);
```

This trigger is supposed to check the date and time attributes, and if the day is a Saturday or a Sunday, or if the time is outside the school business hours (9am to 3pm), a message:

> Out of business hours – this transaction has not completed, please change the
>   date/time

...should be displayed.

Comment: Why do you want to store the `SessionDay`? You can easily get it through the `SessionDate` with `select to_char(SessionDate, 'Day') from sessions;`.

Comment: Why don't you store sessiondate & sessiontime in a single `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) column?

Comment: I was doing another particular exercises with time and date separately as well as day. I found it easier to have it like this.

Comment: With the `SessionDay` in a separate field you need to verify if this day is the same as for the date. Makes is more complicate instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that the check is needed on delete. So create a trigger like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_session_timing
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sessions
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if   :new.SessionDay = 'Saturday'
      or :new.SessionDay = 'Sunday' then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Out of business hours – this transaction has not completed, please change the date/time');
    end if;
    if :new.SessionTime not between 900 and 1500 then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Out of business hours – this transaction has not completed, please change the date/time');
    end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have found it very useful. Seems I was missing that error code in line:   raise_application_error(-20001(...) and I also changed line from  to_char(:new.SessionDate, 'HH24MI') to :new.SessionTime . Now it suits my needs perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Changed my answer. You might consider to use one field for the time instead of the 3 that you use now. This way you avoid 'confusions' like this. The `to_char` and `to_date` functions are used for this combination.

Comment: Alright I deleted the SessionDay, but my trigger is not working properly. I am not sure how to call it now. Something like if to_char(:new.SessionDate, ' Day') = 'Sunday' or how can I specify that it is about the day and it is supposed to know just from the dd/month/yyyy which of the day of the week it is?

Comment: You should use it as `trim(to_char(:new.SessionDate, ' Day'))` because the result of the `to_char` is a string of 9 characters. `Sunday` has 6 so 3 spaces are added which makes that the result is not equal to 'Sunday' but to 'Sunday   '. You can also use `'D'` instead of `'Day'` to get the number of the day of the week. Sunday = 1 and Saturday = 6.

Comment: Amazing, trim solved my problem. Thank you once again.